# Triggered Azure Webjob sporadically not running

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, queuetrigger

We have a webjob that is invoked with a queutrigger that we trigger every time an order is submitted.

```
public async Task OrderJobAsync([QueueTrigger("newshipment")] string filename, TextWriter log) 
{
    doSomething() 
}
```

Over the past week we had some very high order activity and our webjob didn't run for a handful of these orders. We have email and slack notifications set up to send when a webjob fails but those were not triggered at all because the job simply did not run. Does anyone know what could have caused this? Could our order activity have triggered this webjob too many times?

Comment: Did you enable Always On for your Azure App Service?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was fixed by adding the WEB_JOB_IDLE_TIMEOUT setting in our azure configuration.

What I think was happening was that our webjob queue was getting backed up during periods of high order activity and some jobs did not run within the 2:00 minute window that is the default idle timeout. I extended this to be a half an hour and we haven't had this problem since.